# Date picker is not working on dynamically added html element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Date picker is not working on my dynamically added html table input field. I use `clone`function for make dynamic field.

If the parent has value the date picker is not working but it work if the parent is empty. or sometime works sometime not. acting like strange :(

What I am doing wrong can any one help me with this ? Thanks in advance

I am using `jquery-ui` datepicker

**Here is my** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/p9xwd0qr/5)

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1930:-14',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is when you clone the input from the above rows, it'll have the clone the `hasDatepicker` class too which will break it.
To test it, just don't focus the input and add an extra row and focus the second row's input and it'll work.
Here's the solution to this.

```
                $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
                $(this).datepicker({ //Change this line here
```

to

```
                $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({ //Change this line here
```

It will first reset the input then initialize the datePicker

Comment: To add clarification: When you call `.datepicker({` it adds class `hasDatepicker` so that the datepicker module knows not to re-initialise the datapicker when you call `.datepicker({` again.